How to Read Large Files from Servers in Chunks Using Python?
I am working on a hobby project and trying to develop a GPS/GNSS Receiver. The first module of the receiver has two different options i.e. ask the user to connect an SDR or if the user doesn't have an SDR available, the receiver go to https://rnl-data.ae.utexas.edu/datastore/texbat/ and read the signal based on the user's needs.
The problem is, the signals uploaded here are very large files (40+ GB) and we can't wait for the file to download and then process. Therefore, I am thinking to build a module that read the file in chunks and process it. For instance, we may read the first 30 secs of the signal and process it and then move on to the next 30 seconds.
I am using Python and other option I have is MATLAB. Unfortunately I don't know C/C++ so if something like this is possible in Python then please let me know. I know we have the urllib and requests libraries but I just can't scratch my head around it.
P.S I am not expecting a complete code but just a starting direction would be extremely helpful for me.
import requests


url = "https://rnl-data.ae.utexas.edu/datastore/texbat/cleanStatic.bin"


response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
print (response.status_code)

if(response.ok):

    with open('./cleanStatic.bin', 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)

else:
    response.raise_for_status()

But I don't want to store it in local drive. I want to read, process and then discard the data.

I would try to save each chunk in temporary object io. StringIO or io. BytesIO and then try to read chunk and process it.

I assume your code is working. If you don't want to store it in local drive why are you doing it then? Just remove with open('./cleanStatic.bin', 'wb') as fd: and fd.write(chunk). Convert binary chunk to any format it was originally, for example using np.frombuffer()

nobody makes you use fs.write(chunk). do with those chunks whatever you want. you already know about response.iter_content. I don't understand what you are asking. you seem to have all the pieces you're asking for.

I am incredibly sorry for not making myself clear enough. Actually, I want to create a scenario where the software-defined receiver will receive specific chunks of data per iteration, it will process the data by performing acquisition and tracking and then calculate the position and read the next chunk and do the same process again.
